# saving RL agent by pickle, cannot save because of pickle.thread_RLock -- what is the source of this error?

Tags: tensorflow, pickle, openai-gym

I am trying to save my reinforcement learning agent class after training for further training later on by pickling it.

The script used is:

```
with open('agent.pickle','wb') as agent_file:
     pickle.dump(agent,agent_file)
```

I am receiving an error:

```
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

I have searched this error message but not sure what the actual source of the error is. The traceback is uninformative with respect to specifically which line of code is causing this error. The scripts uses come from 3 independent .py files. A tensorflow, keras model has been built in one of them, but again unsure about where specifically this is coming from!I have read this error can come from lambda functions, but none of these are defined by myself, unless they are used internally byu a package such as tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same error but found a workaround. After `model.fit()`, use `model.save("modelName")`. It will make a folder inside which the model will be saved.

To load the model, use `keras.models.load_model("modelName")`

Comment: thank you, i will try and report if it works.